# Java ArrayList contains method not returning expected result

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I'm creating a simple check on an `Arraylist<object>` called "users". The users object has username and password fields. I am creating a method to remove a user and it's not returning the desired result.

```
public void remove(){
    if(users.contains(in.nextLine())) //if ArrayList contains username you want to remove
        users.remove(this);
    else
        System.out.println("There is not a user with that name");
}
```

The problem is when I enter the same exact username as the username that is already in the users ArrayList, it still returns the else statement. I have a hunch that it is because of my `equals/hashcode overrides` in the class it inherits from.. they are just the generic ones generated by Eclipse.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    UserAccount other = (UserAccount) obj;
    if (username == null) {
        if (other.username != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

****EDIT****
Equals override is in the super class "UserAccount". I've created a "FacebookUser" class that inherits UserAccount, and then "Facebook" class that inherits FacebookUser. The "Facebook" class is where my methods in question are. The constructors for each are

```
UserAccount(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}   
Facebook(String username, String password){ //FacebookUser the same
    super(username, password);
}
```

and they are added to the list by this method

```
public void add(){
    System.out.println("Add username..");
    if(users.contains(username = in.nextLine()))
        System.out.println("Already a user of that name");
    else {
        System.out.println("Add password..");
    users.add(new Facebook(username, in.nextLine()));
    }
}
```

Is there a better way I can override equals to make this code work? Thanks to you're responses, I did try `if(users.toString().contains(in.nextLine()))` and that gave the desired result. My toString() override returns `this.username;` Also I made the wrong call here `users.remove(this);`

Comment: You've not posted enough code. I assume that you have a list of UserAccounts but you are checking if it contains specified string. Thus your equals always returns false

Comment: You check if `users` `contains` a `String`, but then remove `this`? What is `users`? What is `this`?

Comment: Your post is missing a few things that prevent us from helping you: The declaration of the arraylist, the class you are putting into the list along with its equals method and if you are invoking its super class's equals that too. It isn't clear where the equals you posted fits into your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `in.nextLine()` returns a `String`, `users.contains()` will never return `true`, because your `User` object's `equals` method produces `false` when you pass any string.

To fix this, call `remove` right away, and compare the result to `null` to decide on the printout:

```
User removed = users.remove(this);
if (removed == null) {
    System.out.println("There is not a user with that name");
}
```

Note that this removes the current user, not a user identified by `in.nextLine()` string. If you want to keep users organized by some string name, use `Map<String,User>` instead of a list.

Comment: Thank you this answer led me to figure it out. I passed an object instead and and now it works. I see now how it fails in the equals method.